# Setting up Angular v2.x and AOT

Tags: angular

I try to set up AOT on my new project with [this tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#compile-with-aot)
but when I compile (using `node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json`) and then run project with `npm serve --aot` I get this message:

> Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.

My main.ts is exactly as in the tutorial.
Maybe it doesn't work because I use angular v2?
For every package install I had to specify a v2 version.

I checked in the "aot" folder and I do have the generated ngFactory files

Comment: don't know about `tsconfig-aot` but I can tell you if you use Angular-CLI it's very straightforward: `ng build -prod` and `ng serve -prod`. Much simpler

Comment: Yes I can run my project without AOT but my goal here is to use AOT

Comment: Sorry, I must have not explained properly. You can achieve AOT with Angular-CLI. where `build -prod` will compile all your resources into the target JS specified, whilst `ng serve -prod` will run the project from the compiled sources only. Or you can just grab the "compiled output" directory and drop it on Tomcat. I hope this clarifies

Comment: build -prod is the regular way to build (and so deliver) the app for production right? AOT brings nothing more? I'm pretty new to angular